# Custom ProMotion TableCell not showing

Tags: ios, ruby, uitableview, rubymotion, rubymotion-promotion

I'm building a tableView with custom cells using RubyMotion and ProMotion. I can't figure out why none of the cells are visible. When I'm not trying to use the custom cell class, the title label is visible. What am I missing here? Thanks! Here is my code:

The TableScreen

```
class HomeScreen < PM::TableScreen
  title 'Overview'

  def on_load
    @welcome_label = UILabel.new
    @welcome_label.text = 'Welcome to PushUp'
  end

  def table_data
    data1 = [1, 2, 3]
    data = [{ number: 1, date: '1.2.2014' }, { number: 5, date: '2.2.2014' }]

    [{
        title: 'PushUps',
        cells:
                   data.map do |e|
                     { cell_class: MyCell, title: e[:anzahl].to_s, date: e[:datum] }
                   end
     }]
  end
end
```

The custom cell:

```
class MyCell < PM::TableViewCell
  attr_accessor :title, :detail

  def layoutSubviews
    @title = newTitleLabel
    @detail = newDetailLabel
    addLabelsToSubview
  end

  def addLabelsToSubview
    Motion::Layout.new do |layout|
      layout.view self.contentView
      layout.subviews "title" => title, "detail" => detail
      layout.vertical "|[title]|"
      layout.vertical "|[detail]|"
      layout.horizontal "|-[title]-10-[detail]-|"
    end
  end

  def newTitleLabel
    label = UILabel.alloc.init
    label.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    label
  end

  def newDetailLabel
    label = UILabel.alloc.init
    label.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleFootnote)
    label
  end
end
```

**Update**

Really weird, when I raked this morning, the cell showed 2 labels. They are both sitting on the left, I think it' some kind of standard iOS cell design, so it's not created by me. But they have the values I gave them.

I then deleted everything from the cell class unless the `initWithStyle` method (call to super and returning self inside it stayed). The cell stayed the same. This means my cell design has no influence on the design of the cell. Have I maybe failed to declare the cell class the correct way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're doing the ProMotion part correctly. What version of PM are you using?

Some debugging steps:

1. Comment out everything inside your `MyCell` and see if it shows the title.
2. If so, then you're doing something wrong with MotionLayout.
3. If it still doesn't work, then it's a PM bug and you can file an issue.

I have a feeling your issue is with MotionLayout, not ProMotion.

Comment: Sorry for the late answerr, I'm using `ProMotion 1.1.2` and `motion-layout 0.0.2`.

Comment: I'll try the things you suggested.

Comment: Can you try `gem 'ProMotion', '~> 2.0.0.rc2'` and see if the problem persists?